# "IF" CLAUSES and the use of WERE

Tags: conditionals

I found this example in The Guardian: *If there were ever a time to join us, it is now*.

Ruling out it is a hypothesis, I found it hard to understand the use of *were* in the sentence. Can somebody explain? Thanks!

Comment: It's a fixed phrase; it doesn't need an explanation. What rules did **you** think it violates?

Comment: The "were" is the subjunctive. It speculates upon the possibility of a time that may or may not have existed in the past.

Comment: Except that modern-day English does not have a subjunctive. This is 'irrealis' _were_, an acceptable and more formal alternant to preterite"was".